# How to deal with dependency when you have separate projects?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dependencies, service-locator

I know there is all this talk about having only one composition root that set all your dependencies and that you should always prefer constructor injection to other types, but sometimes it just doesn't make any sense for me. Here is my pseudo code :

```
    public class FakeModel
    {
        private FakeDependency Dependency = ServiceLocator.Get<FakeDependency>();

        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public FakeModel(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public void UpdateName(string name)
        {
            Dependency.RandomAction();
            Name = name;
        }
    }
```

Special considerations :

- FakeModel and FakeDependency sit in a class library project that is reused my many other projects.
- All the other projects using this class library doesn't know, and shouldn't even know, that FakeDependency exists.
- There will always be only one (+test) implementation of FakeDependency.
- The only reason to replace the FakeDependcy is to run tests that only test the class library.

Would you rewrite this code differently, or it makes sense considering the requirements?

**EDIT**

There seems to be some confusion about the dependency, the service locator and how to use the class library. Think about the model as the public interface of this class library. Everything else is hidden from other projects, is undocumented and subject to changes anytime. You should not ever used any other methods than those define by the model.

About the service locator; it lives inside the class library project. It's only purpose is to make it possible to test the class library and absolutely not to inject new dependencies into this library. If I wanted to make it possible to replace the dependency I would of course have used constructor injection like that `public FakeModel(string name, FakeDependency dependency)` but that is not the case.

Then how do you use this class library currently? Just like that :

```
public void Test()
{
    var model = new FakeModel("MyName");
    model.UpdateName("NewName");
}
```

The class library should be self contained. Maybe using the word "dependency" is confusing as it's not something that you need to provide to the class library.

Comment: The problem with service locators remains unchanged. If the dependency is not found, your application will crash at runtime, and you won't have any idea why. The point of a composition root is that that is the place where things can go wrong.

Comment: Why are you using a service locator? It sounds like what you're doing currently is setting up the dependency binding in the same project as `FakeDependency` lives. That would work just as well with constructor injection.

Comment: I would still prefer to have written this class so that the dependency is injected through the constructor. Also, you say "there will always be only one implementation" and then your very next line illustrates a reason for a second (test) implementation.

Comment: @BenAaronson How would you set it through constructor injection without exposing it to the other projects? You make the constructor internal then you could create it via a factory, but then you would just have moved the ServiceLocator into that factory. Does it add any value?

Comment: @Gudradain The project with `FakeDependency` can expose a module class with a method like `ConfigureBindings(IKernel kernel)` (or whatever type your IOC container uses). Then in the folder where you do your composition, in your application entry project, you can call that method

Comment: Still means you have multiple composition roots, but at least it makes that compatible with constructor injection

Comment: @BenAaronson The other projects don't know anything about the dependencies and hence cannot set them. Doesn't matter if you provide a ConfigureBindings(IKernel kernel). How can you set something that you don't know that exist? And not only that, but other projects don't even know about the service locator. Everything is hidden and encapsulated into the library, the only thing that you know is the model.

Comment: @Gudradain I don't really understand you. Two libraries: InnerLib, AppLib. InnerLib is the one that contains `FakeDependency`. AppLib sets up the IOC container bindings, but one step in that is to call a method on InnerLib called `ConfigureBindings`. `ConfigureBindings` calls methods on the `IKernal` which bind `FakeDependency`. Because `ConfigureBindings` is in InnerLib, it has access to `FakeDependency`. At no point in that process does AppLib need to have any reference to `FakeDependency`, which can be internal.

Comment: @BenAaronson Good point. I didn't think it in that way. But still, what does it add to the InnerLib to require AppLib to know that before using InnerLib you need to create an IKernel and then call CongifureBindings when everything could be done automatically.

Comment: @Gudradain Means you can use dependency injection rather than service location. Google or searching this site will probably give you a lot more on why DI is generally considered very preferable to service location than I could squeeze into this comment box.

Comment: @BenAaronson And where would that DI be used? In the AppLib or InnerLib? How would you use the InnerLib now? You have to accept that if the InnerLib is self contained, its composition root will be located inside it. Then maybe the model is not the right place to have it, and that's my question. Then, how would you create the models and what does it add to change the way they are created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24500/discussion-between-ben-aaronson-and-gudradain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I would rewrite it.

Edit: new code based on your expanded comments and question:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestAssembly")]
    public class FakeModel
    {
        private IFakeDependency dependency;
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public FakeModel(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            this.dependency = new FakeDependency();
        }
        //use this constructor in tests
        internal FakeModel(string name, IFakeDependency dependency)
        {
            Name = name;
            this.dependency = dependency;
        }
        public void UpdateName(string name)
        {
            dependency.RandomAction();
            Name = name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the question is then should `FakeDependency` be bound in the application composition point in the project referencing this one, or in the project which it lives? From my understanding, OP is saying that the former is the standard way of doing this, but has the issues that it means that now `FakeDependency` has to be public and known about by other projects. And also that this same binding has to be repeated in lots of projects.

Comment: hmm I shall add more code..

Comment: @BenAaronson Yup you got it. In fact, FakeDependency should never be used outside the class library project. The Model provides the public interface of the library project and all the other stuffs should stay hidden.

Comment: Ewan, the service locator in the example is a part of the class library project. And no, I don't want to make it easy to change in the sense that you can provide another implementation if you use that class library. If you exclude the tests, there is and should only be one implementation. And all other project using this library shouldn't even bother knowing it.

Comment: I think you will end up exposing it either way. maybe you could add your ServiceLocator code?

Comment: The only way I can see of not exposing it at all is to init the dependency in the model. You might as well just new it up

Comment: By default, the service locator will return the one "true" implementation. When you want to test, you set a "test" implementation. There is nothing else. So, you could replace the the GET code by : return dependency ?? new FakeDependency(); (In fact, the service locator is a wrapper around DI library but the logic is the same).

Comment: well your set method is the weak point then. if you have it the the class is exposed. if you don't then you dont need a service locator

Comment: internal set? then friend assembly for test project? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx

Comment: true, but you still need the ServiceLocator itself to be internal

Comment: It is internal. As other projects have no idea that FakeDependency exists. Other projects have no idea that ServiceLocator exists. The only purpose of ServiceLocator is that if I had written "private FakeDendency Dependency = new FakeDependency()" I would have been unable to write test for FakeModel without also testing FakeDependency.

Comment: It seems like you are squeezing something into a DI/ServiceLocator pattern when you have other options you would be happier with. how about internal void SetTestMode(IFakeDependency dependency) on FakeModel for example?

Comment: If you renamed ServiceLocator and FakeDependency to WidgetFactory and Widget I don't think anyone would raise an eyebrow

Comment: but! if you call it GeneralObjectFactoryThatMakesAllMyobjectsWithAnOptionalTestMode I think I would suggest you just expose the interfaces and use DI

Comment: I like that last solution. The library project is still self contained and testable. From the outside it's perfect but my only grip is 'new FakeDependency()'. FakeDependency might be depending on other dependencies that themselves depend on others. It was kinda my reason to create it via a service locator. All those dependencies use constructor injection of course, because it makes sense there.